# Using Inverse Laplace to find the frequency response of a transfer function - Help needed!

Tags: analysis, laplace-transform, convolution, dirac-delta, inverse-laplace

The frequency response is the inverse Laplace transform of a transfer function. I am tasked to apply the inverse Laplace on the transfer function below  in order to convert it into the time domain.

$$H(s) =\frac{20\cdot10^3s}{{s^2} +{20\cdot10^3s}+{500\cdot10^6}}$$

So far, I have had no success in doing so. Any help in solving this would be greatly appreciated. Note that I have to use Laplace transforms to solve this.

Comment: The symbol $\cdot$ `$\cdot$` is a better multiplication symbol to use.

Comment: Thanks, updated! :)

Comment: Have a look at https://www.emathhelp.net/en/notes/differential-equations/laplace-transform/table-of-laplace-transforms/

Answer (score 2):

The 'trick' is to write
the transfer function in zero-pole form
$$
H(s) 
= \frac{\alpha s}{(s-p)(s-p^*)}
$$
where
$p = a+ib$.

Then use
partial fraction decomposition
to discover that
$$
H(s) 
= 
\frac{\alpha}{p-p^*}
\left[
\frac{p}{s-p}-\frac{p^*}{s-p^*}
\right]
$$

Then you can use inverse Laplace transform
\begin{eqnarray*}
h(t) 
&=& 
\frac{\alpha}{p-p^*}
\left[
p e^{p t} - 
p^* e^{p^* t}
\right]\\
&=& 
\frac{\alpha}{2ib} e^{at}
\left[
p e^{ibt} - 
p^* e^{-ibt}
\right] \\
&=& 
\frac{\alpha}{2ib} e^{at}
\left[
(a+ib) e^{ibt} -
(a-ib) e^{-ibt}
\right] \\
&=& 
\alpha e^{at}
\left[
\cos(bt)+\frac{a}{b} \sin(bt)
\right] 
\end{eqnarray*}

This seems reasonable since
$$
H(s) 
= \frac{\alpha s}{(s-a)^2+b^2}
= \alpha \frac{(s-a)+(a/b)b}{(s-a)^2+b^2}
$$

Comment: Thanks! Will try to apply this and see if I can solve it :)

Comment: Thanks @Steph, got it now!